# what is the theoretical reason behind the new paper, Highly tunable hybrid metamaterials employing split-ring resonators built using graphene?

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, graphene

A few days ago, a group of University of Exeter physicists published a paper titled:

> *Highly tunable hybrid metamaterials employing split-ring resonators strongly coupled to graphene surface plasmons* — Peter Q. Liu, Isaac J. Luxmoore, Sergey A. Mikhailov, Nadja A. Savostianova, Federico Valmorra, Jérôme Faist & Geoffrey R. Nash. *Nature Communications* 6, 8969. [doi:10.1038/ncomms9969](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ncomms9969)

This paper describes how to use graphene to build split ring resonator operating in the terahertz frequency range with a fast switching speed of 20 MHz.

1. What is the physics rationale for this paper's statement that graphene metamaterials are superior to natural rare earth metals in terms of transmission efficiency.
2. Is the tunability of the resonator controlled by the Franz-Keldysh effect?
3. Could this paper's findings be applied to tunable optical filters operating in the visible light wavelengths?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rob, I was wondering if you could comment on this question. Thank you.

Comment: @ptomato, Thank you for the nice edit. Do you have any thoughts on this paper?

Comment: Sorry, I don't; just a passing edit, hoping that an easier-to-read question would get you more attention.